# Sound effect on button click

Tags: iphone, button

I added sound effect in my code . But when i start my app and first click on button it takes some time then work. It happen only on first click otherwise on other button clicks it work quickly. it shows me som error like

```
2012-07-17 12:51:22.240 PainReporter[6882:16503] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen to me. I never figured out exactly why it was happening but, it only happened when running in the simulator.

In addition to this, if you are using `AVFoundation` to play your audio make sure you call `prepareToPlay`. Doing so should help with the time it takes to start playing the sound.